# Is it possible NOT to turn off display when monitoring proximity?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

In loadView I'm adding myself as observer for

```
[nc addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(proximityAlert:)
           name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification
         object:device];
```

then I tell device to start generating those alerts

```
[device setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
```

and I handle them in

```
-(void)proximityAlert:(NSNotification *)note
```

**The problem is that when I cover the sensor for too long, the screen turns off, which in my app's case is not convenient.**

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

`idleTimerDisabled` is not a valid solution to this question. (Not deleting as comments below will go lost if I do.)

Comment: Turning a screen off when covering proximity sensor is not due to idle timer being set on (as far as I know).

Comment: I was wondering about that. Have you confirmed it, for curiosity's sake?

Comment: Sure, it doesn't work in this case ... I guess apple haven't put any accessor for changing this behavior, because I haven't found anything regarding this problem.

Comment: I searched around a bit and came up empty-handed as well. Updated my non-answer to simply say it wasn't an answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway!